# Equalising m integers by adding n to the sum

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

From Arthur Engel's "Problem Solving Strategies":

> Starting with any 35 integers, you may select 23 of them and add 1 to each. By repeating this step one can make all 35 integers equal. Prove this. Now replace 35 and 23 by m and n, respectively. What condition must m and n satisfy to make equalization still possible?

**My Attempt:**
Call $S$ the sum of the $m$ integers initially.

If $gcd (m,n) = 1$, then, by performing moves, the following state can be reached:

$$S + nx = my$$

...which implies that the integers can be written as $m$ equal values of $y$.

If $gcd (m,n) = d > 1$, then $d$ must divide $S$ which may not always be the case.

---

I have reviewed the solution found in the book itself but I am wondering if the above works too.

---

Solution from book:

> Suppose $gcd(m,n) = 1$. Then, by Bezouts identity, we have $nx = my + 1$ has a solution with x and y from {1, 2,..., m-1}. We rewrite this equation in the form $nx = m(y-1) + m +1$. Now we place any m positive integers $x_1,...x_m$ around a circle assuming that $x_1$ is the smallest number. We proceed as follows. Go around the circle in blocks of n and increase each number of a block by 1. If you do this $n$ times you get around the circle $x$ times, and, in addition, the first number becomes one more than the others. In this way |$x_{max} - x_{min}$| decreases by one. This is repeated each time placing a minimal element in front until the difference between the maximal and minimal element is reduced to zero.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. FYI, in case you didn't know, this is related to [Bézout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity).

Comment: Thank you. I have seen this identity before and the solution mentioned it. Would it be helpful if I quoted the book on the answer?

Comment: Added the solution.

Comment: Are you sure you copied the answer exactly? I feel like it should say "If you do this $x$ times, you get around the circle $y$ times, and in addition, ..." Either way, what your statement is missing (which the book has) is a sufficiency condition; you were right to assert the necessity of gcd(m,n)=1; the book tells you why that is sufficient.

Comment: You're right. I was scribbling it down quickly on my phone. Sorry. It says "if you do this n times, you get around the circle m times" - which personally makes less sense than what you said. I am not sure I follow when you talk about the sufficiency condition though. Can you explain?

Comment: Your solution only establishes that "we must have $\gcd(n,m)=1$", IE it is a necessary condition. You failed to demonstrate that it is sufficient, because "implies that the integers can be written as $m$
 equal values of $y$" isn't a true statement. As a counter-example, for $m = 3, n = 2$, if we start with the integers $10, 1, 2$ giving $ S = 13$, we have $ 13 + 2\times 1 = 3\times 5$, so you're suggesting that we can get to a state of $5, 5, 5$, but that's clearly impossible.

Comment: That was pretty comprehensive. Thank you.